# using sql now function and nodejs using util module

Tags: mysql, sql, node.js

If I use MySQL function of Now(), it should bring up the current time and current date.

however the now() function in node js is getting this answer.
 `2018-02-27T00:00:00.000Z` and storing it in the database.

```
var sql = util.format('insert into stocks (Price, Date) values ("%s", NOW())', price1);
```

I am using the Date variable to store the now() function and insert into mysql database.

Any help on how i can get the current time.

Comment: Use [moment.js](https://momentjs.com/).

Comment: or use date format, https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_mysql_date_format.asp, it isn't clear to me from your question on which side the problem is.

Comment: problem has been fixed, the issue was mysql datatype was date and not datetime